# Train data from csv python textblob

Tags: python, csv, nlp, training-data, textblob

I have a CSV file I am trying to train on a classifier. I am using TextBlob. This is my code that does it.

```
with open('train.csv', 'r') as fp:
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format='csv', feature_extractor= get_features)
```

It however does not seem to work. Is this the correct way to train a classifier using a CSV file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What does it mean to "train" a CSV?  Are you trying to concatenate multiple CSV files?

Comment: No. I have a csv file. I have a text and by the side of the text, I have a label (whether it is R or G). I want to know if my above code is the right way to train the classifier using the contents of my csv file.

Comment: Pretty much just training a classifier using a csv file as training data. Sorry if the wording is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the third argument. get_features is not defined. Try this -

```
cl=NaiveBayesClassifier(fp)
```

It worked for me.